# Bokeh crashes when plotting DataFrame to scatter

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

UPDATE 3: Got it to work on python 2, See answer

UPDATE 2: It's running perfectly fine on Python 3.5.2 with the same bokeh version for python 3. I guess that makes it a python 2 specific bug, I'll report it.

UPDATE: I'm using the upstream version of bokeh, 0.12.5 and python 2.7.12
Bokeh crashes when I try to make a scatter plot out of a seemingly valid, pandas dataframe.

I can't find anything wrong with the dataframe, [Here it is in json format](http://termbin.com/s7sq) so you can deserialize it and check it for yourselves.

Here's the traceback

```
File ".../plotting.py", line 13, in scatter
    p=Scatter(df, plot_width=1000, plot_height=500, sizing_mode='stretch_both')
  File "/home/shep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/builders/scatter_builder.py", line 65, in Scatter
    return create_and_build(ScatterBuilder, data, **kws)
  File "/home/shep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/builder.py", line 56, in create_and_build
    chart.add_builder(builder)
  File "/home/shep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/chart.py", line 153, in add_builder
    builder.create(self)
  File "/home/shep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/builder.py", line 512, in create
    chart.add_renderers(self, renderers)
  File "/home/shep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/chart.py", line 148, in add_renderers
    self.renderers += renderers
  File "/home/shep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/core/property/containers.py", line 76, in wrapper
    result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/core/property/containers.py", line 172, in __iadd__
    return super(PropertyValueList, self).__iadd__(y)
  File "/home/shep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/builders/scatter_builder.py", line 95, in yield_renderers
    marker=group['marker'])
  File "/home/shep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/glyphs.py", line 130, in __init__
    super(PointGlyph, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/home/shep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/models.py", line 84, in __init__
    self.setup()
  File "/home/shep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/models.py", line 90, in setup
    self.refresh()
  File "/home/shep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/models.py", line 99, in refresh
    data = self.build_source()
  File "/home/shep/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/glyphs.py", line 57, in build_source
    str_labels = [str(label) for label in labels]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I'd LOVE to know what's wrong with my dataframe and how can I make it work.

Comment: it works with bokeh 0.12.3 in my 3.5 env

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I opened an issue on the Bokeh github](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6218) and apparently you need to specify the X and Y axis for it to work:

```
p=Scatter(df,
    x="Fraction of deaths caused by G20: Parkinson disease",
    y="Fraction of deaths caused by I64: Stroke")
```